# Is my Drupal website hacked?

Tags: 7, security

So I am running this Drupal 7 website, I just checked users list and got surprised with this:
[image]

As you can see the usernames are spam and their emails are also spam. But I do not get it how they did that and even get themselves an admin role. Also log shows they even enabled the php filter module. Also the registrations are disabled so how? Even if the users where registered via site register form it would show its 1 week old or so, not the 44 years.

I don't get it. What should I do? Also I have User Protect module installed.

Comment: sure looks like it - take a look at [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133996/drupal-sa-core-2014-005-how-to-tell-if-my-server-sites-were-compromised) for further information - I presume you are using a version below 7.32?

Comment: You are right it's 7.31. How do I select you as correct answer?

Comment: You need to upgrade you version of Drupal immediately to the latest version available. There was a major security vulnerability found recently. More information on testing and cleansing can be found in [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133996/drupal-sa-core-2014-005-how-to-tell-if-my-server-sites-were-compromised).

Comment: Take a look at this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138359/cant-access-my-website

Comment: Please note, that since you have been hacked already, there is no real fix anymore. In most cases, the hackers actually patched your site (in order to keep other hackers away). But your server has been compromised now. The only secure way is to rollback to a backup prior to October 15th (not just Drupal but your whole file system and databases).